# Resolve Array length in Angular UI-grid and dynamically enable/disable paging

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am getting a nested collection from service. When i am mapping field to Array with Array.length it is giving me output. BUT when i try
  field: `Auditlogs[Auditlogs.length-1].auditState.StateName` . It stops working. Please help me on this.

I also want to disable Pagination based on a Flag in `$scope`. Below is my ui-grid setting

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'auditList',
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    enablePaginationControls: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    enableSorting: true,       
    useExternalPagination: true,
    columnDefs: [
         {
             name: 'LOAN #',
             cellTemplate: '<a ng-click="grid.appScope.getLoanDetails(row.entity.Loan.LoanNumber,row.entity.Id)">{{row.entity.Loan.LoanNumber}}</a>'
             ,enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Audit Type',
             field: 'AuditType.AuditType1'
             ,enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Borrower Last Name',
             field: 'Loan.BorrowerLastName'
             ,enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Funding Date',
             field: 'Loan.FundingDate',
             type: 'date',
             cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'',
             enableFiltering: false
             ,enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Audit start date',
             field: 'AuditStartDate',
             type: 'date',
             cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\''
             ,enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Due Date',
             field: 'AuditStartDate',
             type: 'date',
             cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\''
             ,enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Finding Count',                 
             field: 'AuditFindings.length',
             enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Current Status',
             field: 'Auditlogs[Auditlogs.length-1].auditState.StateName'                 
//$scope.auditList[0].Auditlogs[$scope.auditList[0].Auditlogs.length-1].auditState.StateName
             ,enableHiding: false
         },
         {
             name: 'Cur.Status Dt.',
             field: 'AuditStartDate',
             type: 'date',
             cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\''
             ,enableHiding: false
         }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
            $scope.paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
            $scope.paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
            $scope.getAllPA($scope.flagValue.value);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please provide complete controller, service code or a plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the above issue by using CellTemplate instead of Feild

```
cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity.Auditlogs[row.entity.Auditlogs.length-1].auditState.StateName}}</div>'
```

I am still looking to dynamically enable/disable pagination on Grid.

Comment: fixed Dynamic paging by storing flag in scope and assignig scope value to gridoptions